# jquery and cookie status

Tags: jquery, toggle, setcookie

What i'm trying to do is have a sidebar toggle open and close which is working fine but I also want cookie to remember the sidebar state when browsing site and when returning to page its on

ie: if closed be closed if open be open:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('a#side').click(function(){
  $('#sidebar').toggle();
$('a#side').text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
  $.cookie('side_cookie', 'value');
 return false;
});
if($.cookie('side_cookie')) { 
$('#sidebar').hide(); 
   } else {
$('#sidebar').show();
   }
});
```

The current code above just remembers if its been closed and stays closed until session is ended and so you have to toggle it open each time you return to page ...

An example of what im trying to achieve can be seen at vbulletin.com/forum/ if you close their sidebar  then browse the forums when you go back to main page its still closed and visa versa.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thx guys but I got it sorted, its alot more code then I wanted as its alot of .show()/.hide() rather then .toggle() buts it works sofor now it will do:

```
$('a#hide').click(function(){
  $('a#hide,#sidebar').hide();
  $('a#show').show();
  $.cookie('side_cookie_hidden', 'hidden');
  $.cookie('side_cookie_show', null);
 return false;
});

$('a#show').click(function(){
  $('a#show').hide();
  $('a#hide,#sidebar').show();
  $.cookie('side_cookie_show', 'show');
  $.cookie('side_cookie_hidden', null);
 return false;
});

if($.cookie('side_cookie_hidden')) { 
$('a#show').show();
$('a#hide,#sidebar').hide(); 
   } else {
$('a#show').hide();
$('a#hide,#sidebar').show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with if condition if($.cookie('side_cookie')).
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
 $('a#side').click(function(){
  $('#sidebar').toggle();
$('a#side').text($(this).text() == 'Show' ? 'Hide' : 'Show');
  $.cookie('side_cookie', $(this).text());
 return false;
});
if($.cookie('side_cookie')=='Hide') { 
$('#sidebar').hide(); 
   } else {
$('#sidebar').show();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the value of the cookie rather than its existence. Also you are hardcoding the value of the cookie as `value`. Change it to `show` or `hide`.

```
// when it is shown
$.cookie('side_cookie', 'show');

// when it is hidden

$.cookie('side_cookie', 'hide');
```

and check the value of the cookie

```
if($.cookie('side_cookie') === "show") {
    // code for showing side bar
}
else {
    // code for hiding the side bar
}
```

Comment: Is that not what Cybernate's example shows? ..he tryed to use $(this).text() to set the cookie value but it didnt work ....if its not could you shown an example as this is the first time using cookies thx.